# Updating a cell in datatable by jquery, Jquery Datatable version 1.10

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I need to update the Total amount Whenever the Qtde is updated
The total value is the multiplication of Qtde and Value, the table is dynamically loaded with json

However I'm struggling to pick up the value of aaData, my table is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset=utf-8>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- jQuery (necessario para os plugins Javascript Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


        <script> 


            var testeJson = [{"id":"58","country_code":"UK","title":"Legal Director","pubdate":"2012-03-08 00:00:00","value":"1234"},{"id":"59","country_code":"UK","title":"Solutions Architect,","pubdate":"2012-02-23 00:00:00","value":"54343"},{"id":"60","country_code":"UK","title":"Solutions Architect,","pubdate":"2012-02-23 00:00:00","value":"35312"}];
            var Total;

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var OTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "aaData": testeJson,

        "aoColumns": [ 
            {"sTitle": "select","mDataProp": null, "sDefaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' id ='check01'></input>", "bSortable": false},
            { "mDataProp": "id",sTitle: "id" },
            { "mDataProp": "country_code", sTitle: "country_ ode" },
            { "mDataProp": "title", sTitle: "Titulo" },
            { "mDataProp": "pubdate", sTitle: "Update" },
            { "mDataProp": "value", sTitle: "value" },
            { "mDataProp": null, sTitle: "Qtde", "sDefaultContent": "<input type='text' id='QtdeId' required='required' value='0'/>" },
            { "mDataProp": null, sTitle: "Total", "sDefaultContent": Total }



            ],


    });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#08s")
            .click(function () {

            $(".check01").each(function(){
                    $("check01:checked", table.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){
                        console.log($(this).val());
                    });
                });

            var teste = OTable.fnGetData();

        alert(JSON.stringify(teste));

        });

        });
            }

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#example1').DataTable( {
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [

                { title: "Id" },
                { title: "Nome do Produto" },
                { title: "Unidade" },
                { title: "Preço Unitário" },
                { title: "Qtde" },
                {title: "Total"}

            ]
        });

    } );
            function teste(OTable){
                var teste = OTable.fnGetData();
        alert(teste.id);    
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {    
        $(":checkbox").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('check01');

        });    
    });
        </script>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="1" width="70%">
    <input type="button" name="botao-ok" value="Ok" id="08s">
```